# i use simple stream function to write data bytes on to the server creating a new text file.

Tags: c#, ftp, stream

sometimes these bytes are not written and creates  empty text files. how can i check that the file written are having data.

```
            ftp.KeepAlive = true;
            ftp.UseBinary = true;
            ftp.UsePassive = false;

            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilepath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            fs.Close();

            ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
            ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

problem: this stream does not support seek operations

Answer (score 0):

Flush your streams. Sometimes the size of the input is too small for the buffer to be flushed automatically, so you have to call flush method at the point you are interested the actual file will be written.
[Stream.Flush Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx)